# Triple finger tap for middle click?

Tags: macos, trackpad

I can single tap my trackpad for a left click, and tap it with two fingers for a right click. Is there any way to bind a three finger tap to perform a middle click?

I tried MagicPrefs, but it's limited to the MagicMouse only, it doesn't work with the trackpad.

Comment: Not sure about 2011, but MagicPrefs now does work with a trackpad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [**BetterTouchTool**](https://folivora.ai/). There might be a setting to do that. Maybe you'll even find another gesture to triple-click that you'll like better.

Answer (score 10):

There is also another tool that I like more then BetterTouchTool,
it's called [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/) and does exactly what you expect :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for to get middle-click paste working on a virtual machine. Thanks!

Comment: Original MiddleClick is not maintained anymore but there is a [fork](https://github.com/artginzburg/MiddleClick-Ventura) of the project.

Comment: after installing, I can only use the feature with tapping. how to enable clicking for the trackpad?