# Three finger click to middle click?

Tags: karabiner

According to [Triple finger tap for middle click?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7110/triple-finger-tap-for-middle-click) there is a old solution to set up three finger **touch** using various tools, but no mention of Karabiner Elements.

Is there a way to configure **Karabiner Elements** to map three finger **click** to middle click?  I have a MacBook Pro 16".

Comment: How is the question you linked obsolete? The accepted answer references a tool that has full support for Apple Silicon and macOS Big Sur.

Comment: I think the "duplicate" is for a different use case - in particular it's for three finger *tap* and has no answers for Karabiner Elements.  "Obsolete" is probably a pretty strong word, I was implying the information appears almost a decade old,, so wondered if it made sense to re-ask in the context of newer tools like KE.